# Why is text disappearing from my answer? This doesn't happen when I disable javascript

Tags: bug, status-completed, javascript, tables

Take a look at the answer here:
[**music.stackexchange answer**](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/26802/how-to-buy-the-right-power-attenuator-for-a-tube-amplifier/26818#26818)

I use semi-ascii formated tables.
They show up in editing mode.
But they disappear shortly after 1 sec when the question page loads.

When I disable JavaScript for the page, the tables are there. I assume there's a script which removes the tables for some reason.

Tested in firefox, opera and chrome.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Somebody edited the answer with adding the <pre> </pre> tags. That fixed the issue.

Comment: music.se is using jTab to render guitar chord and tab notation, and in this case we're too eager about it -- your tables clearly aren't tab notation, but they're treated as such and converted to a graphical notation. Which they clearly don't have, so it comes out empty. I'm looking at it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was the work (but not the fault) of [jTab](http://jtab.tardate.com/), which is used on Music Stack Exchange to render guitar chord notation. We were telling jTab to handle each and every `<pre><code>` block we could find; especially every indented block like the ones you created. jTab dutifully converted them to a graphical representation, but of course your tables don't actually contain any musical notation, and so these graphics came up empty.

That's why NReilingh's edit that used `<pre>` (instead of indentation and thus `<pre><code>`) fixed this particular issue.

From now on, we only give those code blocks to jTab for rendering that pass a simple "this looks lite jTab notation" check; this check wouldn't have passed for your tables and thus they would've been ignored by jTab.